# karma/angularjs how to test run block with an asynchronous service

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

How can I test like:

### init.js lama.system module

```
angular.module('lama.system', [])
   .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        // Crossdomain requests not allowed if you want do cors request see filter.php 
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    }])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$log', 'Global',function ($rootScope, $state, $log, Global) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$log = $log;
        $rootScope.global = Global;
    }]);
```

### controllers.js lama.system module

```
angular.module('lama.system')
    .controller('SystemController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
           $scope.test =[];

         }
    ]);
```

### services.js lama.system module

```
angular.module('lama.system')
    .factory('Menus', ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
            query : function(menus){
                return $http.get('/api/v1/user/menus', {
                    params: {
                        'menus[]': menus
                    }
                });
            }
        }; 
    }]);
```

### system.js router

```
//Setting up route
angular.module('lama.system')
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            $stateProvider              
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'system/views/home.html',
                controller:'SystemController'
            });
        }
    ]);
```

### init.js lama module

```
angular.module('lama', ['ui.router','restangular','lama.system','lama.users'])
    .run(['$rootScope',  'Menus',function ($rootScope, Menus) {
       // Default hard coded menu items for main menu
           var menus = [
            {
                'permission': null,
                'title': 'Home',
                'link': 'home'
            },
            {
                'permission': 'users',
                'title': 'User',
                'link': 'user_actions.list'
            }
            ];

            $rootScope.menus = [];

            function queryMenu(menus) {
                Menus.query(menus).then(
                    function (result) {
                        $rootScope.menus = result.data; 
                    },
                    function (reason) {
                        throw new Error(reason);
                    }
                    );
            }

            // Query server for menus and check permissions
            queryMenu(menus);

           $rootScope.$on('loggedin', function(event,user) {
                console.log('kkk');
                queryMenu(menus);

                $rootScope.global = {
                    user:  user,
                    authenticated: user.groups.length,
                    isAdmin:  user.groups.indexOf('Admins')
                };
            });


    }]);
```

### The test

```
(function() {
    describe('Unit test: system module', function () {
        describe('SystemController', function () {

            // load the controller's module
            beforeEach(function() {
                module('lama');
                module('stateMock');
            });

            var SystemController,
            $rootScope,
            $scope,
            $httpBackend;

            // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
            beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_) {
                $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
                $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
                $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
                SystemController = $controller('SystemController', {
                    $scope: $scope
                });
                $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/v1/user/menus').respond(200,{});
            }));

            it('should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope', function () {
                expect($scope.test.length).toBe(0);
            });

            it('should expose some global scope', function() {
                expect($rootScope.global).toBeTruthy();
            });
        });

    });
}());
```

### that give me :(

```
grunt test
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.21 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/whisher/public_html/public/users/tests/unit/**/*.js" does not match any file.
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux)]: Connected on socket zK1SplAjTHe4x5sAM9ew with id 16331650
WARN [web-server]: 404: /api/v1/user/menus?menus%5B%5D=%7B%22permission%22:null,%22title%22:%22Home%22,%22link%22:%22home%22%7D&menus%5B%5D=%7B%22permission%22:%22users%22,%22title%22:%22User%22,%22link%22:%22user_actions.list%22%7D
WARN [web-server]: 404: /system/views/home.html
ERROR: 'Error: [object Object]
    at http://localhost:9876/base/public/init.js?c7a481724bcf81e4810141349c93d0f698a18904:34
    at http://localhost:9876/base/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?4b4cffd940f7a29168096212664973432d1d7449:100
    at http://localhost:9876/base/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?4b4cffd940f7a29168096212664973432d1d7449:100
    at http://localhost:9876/base/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?4b4cffd940f7a29168096212664973432d1d7449:101
    at http://localhost:9876/base/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?4b4cffd940f7a29168096212664973432d1d7449:112
    at http://localhost:9876/base/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?4b4cffd940f7a29168096212664973432d1d7449:109
    at http://localhost:9876/base/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?4b4cffd940f7a29168096212664973432d1d7449:112
    at h (http://localhost:9876/base/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?4b4cffd940f7a29168096212664973432d1d7449:72)
    at x (http://localhost:9876/base/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?4b4cffd940f7a29168096212664973432d1d7449:77)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?4b4cffd940f7a29168096212664973432d1d7449:78'
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.039 secs / 0.065 secs)

Done, without errors.
```

**NB**

I'm using ui-router

Comment: where is the request to `/system/views/home.html` coming from?

Comment: It comes from system.js router I've updated the code thanks for the help :)

Comment: btw you can find all the code https://github.com/whisher/lama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a look at your source code. The primary offending item is:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['lama']);
});
```

By including your manual bootstrap in the files that karma imports, your app is un-necessarily being bootstrapped within the karma test environment. So, instead, move your `lama` module into a separate file, and omit `init.js` from your files to be included by karma.

There are also a couple of other design concerns that are causing excessive test setup. When testing `SystemController` there is no need to include anything but the `lama.system` module (as this is what the controller belongs to). Your test setup for this controller can be as simple as:

```
var $scope, $rootScope;

beforeEach(module('system.lama'));

beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_) {
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  $controller('SystemController', {$scope: $scope});
}));
```

You will note that in isolating the `lama.system` module as above, you will get an error that `$state` cannot be injected (not found). This is because your module definition should instead be:

```
angular.module('lama.system', ['ui.router'])
```

(A module should not require the presence of another module for its own dependencies, else it can never function in isolation).

One final observation on your mocking for the `lama` module `run` block. Strictly speaking you should stub the service `query` method entirely and not just part of its implementation, else your test is completely isolated. Therefore, instead, it would be better to do the following:

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('Menus', function($delegate, $q) {
     // overwrite the query method
     $delegate.query = function() {
       return $q.when([{id: 1, name: 'Bob'}]);
     };    
     return $delegate; 
  });
}));
```

This way, you don't need to worry about using `$httpBackend` at all.

Comment: Thanks an other ton for the tips. (A module should not require the presence of another module for its own dependencies, else it can never function in isolation). So if I've got for instance lama.system lama.users I should do like angular.module('lama.system', ['ui.router']) angular.module('lama.users', ['ui.router']) instead of angular.module('lama', ['ui.router','restangular','lama.system','lama.users']) ? but doing so you don't go against DRY principle ?

Comment: [So, instead, move your lama module into a separate file, and omit init.js] mmm lama module it's just a container to bootstrap the app so imo apart of testing it make no sense to put it in a separate file

Comment: What's about the code in the run block before it was in system/controllers HeaderController do you think could be a good idea to put it in a directive I don't find the right place :(

Comment: 1. It doesn't violate DRY, because it's still the the same module; it's just being required elsewhere. 2. The problem is your `lama` module is defined in `init.js` so there's no way to include the module for testing without the bootstrap running. 3. I would personally move any code I wish to test/stub from a `run` block and into its own service.